Facing the error throw new MongooseError('Model.find() no longer accepts a callback');
router.get('/list',(req,res) =\>{
Student.find((err , docs) =\>{
if(!err){
res.render('student/list', {
list: docs,

            })
        }else{
            console.log('Error in retrieval: '+ err)
        }
    })

})

I have tries the code with async and await but getting the unable to connect error.
